# GetModuleHandle does not work properly

Tags: c++, winapi

After debugging and trying to fix this issue for several hours, I'm at the point to try to solve this once again before giving up this project.

Given the following code I try to inject a DLL into Solitaire with the purpose to manipulate the score but it won't work, the app crashes on the final manipulation.

```
void SetGameTime(int time)
{
MessageBox(NULL, "Func just begins here - ", "Func start", MB_OK | MB_ICONHAND);
DWORD baseAddress = (DWORD) GetModuleHandle(0);
baseAddress = *(DWORD *) (baseAddress + BASE_OFS_DEF);

DWORD temp  = *(DWORD *)(baseAddress + SCORE_OFS1_DEF);
DWORD temp2 = *(DWORD *)(temp + SCORE_OFS2_DEF);
*(DWORD*) temp2 = 500; // solitaire crashes right here
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? I tried to get the wrong logic while using a debugger that yields, that 'eax' is 0 due to the whole function.

Output of debugger:

```
    SetGameTime(500);
703E1284  push        10h  
703E1286  push        703E3170h  
703E128B  push        703E317Ch  
703E1290  push        0  
703E1292  call        dword ptr ds:[703E30ACh]  // GetModuleHandle operation (?)
703E1298  push        0  
703E129A  call        dword ptr ds:[703E3000h]  // base Address operation (?)
703E12A0  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+97074h]  // eax keeps zero so the wrong function has to be GetModuleHandle?
703E12A6  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+2Ch]  // first offset of score
703E12A9  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+10h]  // and the second one...
703E12AC  mov         dword ptr [eax],1F4h  // unhandled exception, no access to write at pos 0x00000000
    return 0;
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the first call is the MessageBox, the second call is the GetModuleHandle call

Comment: Since GetModuleHandle is returning NULL (which means it failed) do what the docs say and call GetLastError to find out the reason for the error.

Comment: oh thanks, I'm not very familar with ASM yet. Yes I tried to get the Last Error on a MSG Box but it returns null, MSG Box stays empty for some reason.

Comment: why do you treat handle as a pointer?

Comment: Are you on 32 or 64 bit? Your code assumes that the handle (actually a pointer) can be casted to 32 bit. I don't know if the there is a 64 bit version of solitair.

Comment: Using it as a pointer since I'm trying to access another pointer which is pointed by the base adr. + ofs. And yes, there are both 32 and 64 bit versions of solitaire. I'm using 32 Bit win7

Comment: I am aware of that, but I can't find it documented anywhere that HMODULE is actually a base address (R. Chen's blog doesn't count :).

Comment: Really? Used to spend some time to research and found many sources (e.g. gamehacking forums) where they used the function casted to DWORD for getting the base address of the module and that worked for them.

Comment: Many implementation details get abused like that. However, I found this statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx >> `A handle to the DLL module. The value is the base address of the DLL. The HINSTANCE of a DLL is the same as the HMODULE of the DLL`. I guess it can be treated as a feature then (R. Chen uses it as an argument, so I guess it's safe :)

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` is known to work. It is your code that is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the return value. Here's from `GetModuleHandle` docs:

```
If the function fails, the return value is NULL. 
To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
```

The shown assembly is interpreted incorrectly. Here's what it does:

```
SetGameTime(500);
703E1284  push        10h         // four arguments of MessageBox call
703E1286  push        703E3170h  
703E128B  push        703E317Ch  
703E1290  push        0  
703E1292  call        dword ptr ds:[703E30ACh]  // MessageBox call
703E1298  push        0                         // argument for GetModuleHandle()
703E129A  call        dword ptr ds:[703E3000h]  // GetModuleHandle call
```

I think that your comment `// eax keeps zero...` is misleading.

The call to `GetModuleHandle` (this is `703E129A  call ptr ds:[703E3000h]`) doesn't return 0, it returns 0x400000. Plase check in the debugger and, if needed, call GetLastError() to see why, but I am sure it is OK.

Here's also a good tip if you use Visual Studio. Add following to your debugger's watch window: `@err, hr`. This will ensure that you always see the value of the last error, and also the corresponding message, if there is one.

Your constants (BASE_OFS_DEF & co) seem to be invalid. Where do you get them from? You read the content of `baseAddress + BASE_OFS_DEF` and treat it as a valid address, but I believe it is not. Later on you do the similar with SCORE_OFS2_DEF.

It seems that value written at address `temp + SCORE_OFS2_DEF` is 0 and you assign it to `temp2`, thus getting the access violation. Monitor `baseAddress`, `temp` and `temp2` in debugger and you will see.

Comment: The module handle is the base memory address of that module.

Comment: I am aware that it is implemented that why, but it is not a documented feature, right?

Comment: Never saw that in a documentation, found that due to research. But how I'm displaying 'GetLastError()' correctly? Trying to put it as a MSG Box doesn't actually work, getting null. Any ideas how to format that correctly so I get the result displayed in one way or another? Read something about 'FormatMessage' but dunno if this works here..

Comment: @Zdelslav Vojkovic: It's not documented by MS AFAIK, but it's known to work on all current Windows versions (don't know about RT or Phone). It is so widely used and accepted. MS won't dare to change this behavior.

Comment: 'research' means that it is an implementation details, which can change anytime (and, AFAIK, it already change once long ago). Where do you want to display the last error? Why not just write it to debug output (`OutputDebugString` API). Even better, why don't you just step through your code with debugger and see the values?

Comment: @cdoubleplusgood I like that line of logic :) `MS won't dare`. Luckily I don't have to maintain that code ;)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: He's trying to cheat in Solitair. Do you think this code needs to be maintained for 20 years?

Comment: you have the point there :) actually, I was genuinely interested and found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx >> `A handle to the DLL module. The value is the base address of the DLL. The HINSTANCE of a DLL is the same as the HMODULE of the DLL`, so it is kinda official

Comment: After calling GetLastError esi and eax are zero now. Guess that esi represents GetLasError() then, right? (assuming there is only that function added to the code posted by me)

Comment: just add the line `DWORD error = GetLastError()` to your code and you won't have to guess. However, it should be `eax` that contains return value. Or just use `@err, hr` trick from the answer.

Comment: @Mostey, after better look at your code, I have edited the answer. it seems that that you are reading the values from the magic addresses within process space, but they are not what you expect.

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic Solved.

    DWORD temp  = *(DWORD *)(baseAddress + SCORE_OFS1_DEF);
    DWORD temp2 = *(DWORD *)(temp + SCORE_OFS2_DEF);
    *(DWORD*) temp2 = 500; // solitaire crashes right here

was wrong, there actually were no problems with GetModuleHandle()

replaced with:

    DWORD * temp  = (DWORD *)(baseAddress + SCORE_OFS1_DEF);
    DWORD * temp2 = (DWORD *)(*temp + SCORE_OFS2_DEF);
    *temp2 = 500; 

Anyways, got some experience with debuggers now so it wasn't a waste of time. :)
works now, thanks to anyone who answered and helped to solve this!